# Remove scrollbar in all tables subplots generated with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

I have a plot which contains subplots, this subplots are tables. My problem is that I need to export this plot into an image (.png, .jpg) but some of these tables have a scrollbar, so when I export the plot the tables with the scrollbar don't show all the data.

I need to export this plot with all the tables showing their data, is there any way that I can remove this scrollbar so the image can show the entire content??

Here is an example with one table that has this scrollbar (I have censored the content for legal reasons):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data script is not presented either, so it may not be accurate, but you will need to manually set the height at which the scrolling does not appear in the layout update.

```
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    height=1200,
    showlegend=False,
    title_text="test",
)
```

Comment: I have set the height but it doesn't fix the problem. Since a don't know how many tables will generate, If I set a very big height the distance between tables will be huge. I wish I could modify each table in an individual way, this way I could change its height depending on the number of rows.

Comment: You may get a faster resolution if you present specific data and code.